# When is it time to change out batteries in multimeters?

Tags: dc, multimeter, battery-operated, low-battery

On my multimeter, the D.C. voltage readings get inaccurate over time due to battery discharge.

How can I tell when to change out the batteries?

By consulting the manuals, I found what is displayed when the battery needs replacement.

Thanks.

Comment: When it is displaying something like "Lo" when you power it up.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. My meter does not show Lo. Just the d.c. voltage of my battery or circuit being tested.

Comment: Most meters will have a warning that tells when to change the battery.  Check the user's guides of your meters to see how each tells you when the battery is low.

Answer (score 1):

Most meters will have a battery low indication. A good quality meter will have one that comes on before any readings start to become inaccurate.

If you have a variable power supply, you can test your meter by using that instead of the battery. Wind the supply voltage down, and note the voltage at which the low battery warning comes on. Do the same when measuring a constant DC voltage (of near full scale), and when measuring a resistor on ohms range. At what meter supply voltage do the readings change?

Comment: I made a variable power supply a  few years ago. It's not pretty but it outputs 1.7 volts DC to about 12.5 volts. The led meter readings of the power  output supply compare to the readings of  multimeter to at least one decimal place. I figured to post such a picture in my post would not have any relevance to my question. @Neil_UK

Comment: @fixit7 sounds like you're fully equipped to make the experiment then, or you can just trust the meter's LO BATT display.

Answer (score 0):

By consulting the manuals, I found what is displayed when the battery needs replacement.

Comment: Since your question was how to know when to change batteries, your answer does not actually answer that question. If you now know how to determine when to change the batteries, edit it into your answer.

Comment: @Justme I edited my question and took out what did not apply.